# JavaScript create input fields

Tags: php

At the moment i create this page here: http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Design_1.0/index.php?content=create_tutorial

If you press on the button "schritt hinzufügen" you will get one more step. I did it complete with PHP, but now i want to do it with JS. But im a totaly noob in JS. Should i use normal JS or jquery? I found many jsfiddles in the Internet, but im to low to use it. Maybe ssomeone of you can help me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

I started with jQuery, because it is much less typing (and I found it easier to learn). Don't listen to those who say you must learn javascript first -- I didn't and I am now filling-in what I missed about javascript after having designed numerous sites.

I also found these great tutorials:

1. PHPAcademy.org
   [jQuery Basics](https://phpacademy.org/videos/jquery-basics)
2. TheNewBoston.com
   [Intro to jQuery](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)